# Add an Expires or a Cache-Control header in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, http, cache-control

How do you add an `Expires` or a `Cache-Control` header in JSP? I want to add a far-future expiration date in an include page for my static components such as images, CSS and JavaScript files.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To disable browser cache for JSP pages, create a `Filter` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `*.jsp` and does basically the following in the `doFilter()` method:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

This way you don't need to copypaste this over all JSP pages and clutter them with *scriptlets*.

To enable browser cache for static components like CSS and JS, put them all in a common folder like `/static` or `/resources` and create a `Filter` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/static/*` or `/resources/*` and does basically the following in the `doFilter()` method:

```
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L); // 1 week in future.
```

**See also:**

- [Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)
- [Webapplication performance tips and tricks.](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html)

Comment: thanks it helped me much. But isn't there an error on the seconde line? Imho it should be: httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");

Comment: I found this article from a book: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index2.html, they set some extra headers for IE, `// Set IE extended HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers (use addHeader).
  res.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");`

Comment: @Christophe: that's a myth. That applies only to cacheable resources. You don't need this on a resource which is already not cacheable. You see this additional header often when one made the mistake that a page was unintentionally served as cacheable and then the developer fixed it by making it non-cacheable. However, without those 2 directives it would still stick around in IE until the enduser explicitly clears IE cache themselves.

Comment: When I did this nothing was coming over the screen.
I have two filters 
1> <filter-name>myApp</filter-name> for this url pattern as <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
2> <filter-name>CacheManagerFilter</filter-name> for this url pattern as <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>  , might be this is the problem ? how can I handle this situation ?

Comment: Apparently you forgot to continue the filter chain.

Comment: @BalusC setting expires to -1 would be a better advise and never use Expires = 0 to prevent caching. The Expires header is sent by the remote server and passed through to the browser by the Portal Server. Unless the time on all three machines is synchronized, an Expires=0 header can mistakenly return cached content. To solve this problem, set the Expires header to a fixed date that is definitely in the past or -1.

Comment: @pokemonblue Uhm, code uses `setDateHeader()` not `setHeader()`.

Comment: Is there any reason you chose to write your own `Filter` rather than using `Tomcat`'s predefined `Filter`: [`ExpiresFilter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/ExpiresFilter.html)?

Comment: @theyuv: so that the webapp can run on any other server than Tomcat. Using a Tomcat-specific filter would tight-couple the webapp to be deployable on Tomcat only. This tight-coupling is a bad practice. Use Tomcat built-in filter only as being server operator to fix an existing train wreck webapp without need to modifiy its source code.

Answer (score 10):

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```

Comment: OP says he wants a page that expires in the far future, yet this answer gives him the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
```

Comment: Should both "Cache-Control" and "Pragma" be used or only one depending in the servlet Container?

Comment: OP says he wants a page that expires in the far future, yet this answer gives him the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Servlet containers like Tomcat come with a set of predefined filters. See for example [Expires Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Expires_Filter). It may be easier to use existing one than to create your own similar filter.