# Set HTTP Caching Expiration, Recommended by Google PageSpeed and Yahoo for weblogic

Tags: web-applications, weblogic, web

I want to set this expiration for weblogic, here is the description:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html

I see a lot of examples how to do it in Apache using .htaccess file but I don't see examples for weblogic.

Can someone please provide an example how to set expiration of static content far in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weblogic does not have a config file to do this. 
You'll have to do this in your JSP code (all of them using Pragma HTTP Headers) or using a Filter for all static files such as CSS and images.

There is a good example in BalusC's answer to this question

[Add an Expires or a Cache-Control header in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3055268/289396)

Specifically

```
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L); // 1 week in future.
```

Comment: JSP won't work because I need to refresh the JSP every time, but I import some static content in the JSPs and want to cache that content - images, css, javascript. I guess I'll need to write a filter then.