# Alternate of http-equiv = "pragma" and http-equiv = "cache-control" in meta tags

Tags: html, jsp, w3c-validation

In my JSP file for cache control, I have used pragma directives as

```html
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" >
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" >
```

But while validating my page from w3c validator I am getting following errors

> Bad value pragma for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
>
> Bad value cache-control for attribute http-equiv on element meta.

So I am looking for alternative methods to pass the w3c validation on this scenario.

PS: I am a beginner in JSP and HTML. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [HTTP headers instead](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#META).

[You can set them using `setHeader`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055268/add-an-expires-or-a-cache-control-header-in-jsp) e.g.

```
 httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
```

Comment: I have used http headers but I have read somewhere that to disable the cache on local I have to use meta tags as mentioned above. In my JSP scriptlet, I have added HTTP headers.

Comment: @MayurSoni — You've read wrong. Meta http equiv is a bad joke. Real HTTP headers are the correct way to deal with the problem.